# How can i refactor this? And also make less calls to the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refactoring

i have this method. Its job is to return a list of trainees who have now graduated to developers. The user filters what skills they are looking for in a developer. The list is returned with the more relevant developers on the top of the list

this is the controller method:

```
  def filter
    @skills = Skill.all
    @developers = []
    unless params[:ids].nil?
      params[:ids].each do |skill|
        skill = @skills.find(skill)
        skill.trainees.each do |developer|
          @developers << developer
        end
      end
    end
    if @developers.empty?
      @developers = Trainee.developers.all
    else
      @developers = @developers.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k, v| [k, v.count]}
      @developers.sort_by!(&:last).reverse!
      @developers.map! do |developer|
        developer[0]
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

Currently, this same method is hitting the server more times that i would like. the server log below is showing as a result of me clicking 11 buttons to filter with. can be 1 or 5 or 20 depending on what the user is looking for

```
Processing by SkillsController#filter as */*
  Parameters: {"ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]}
  Skill Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 1
  Skill Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 2
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 3
  Skill Load (6.1ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 4
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 5
  Skill Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 6
  Skill Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 7
  Skill Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 8
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 9
  Skill Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 10
  Skill Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `skills`.* FROM `skills` WHERE `skills`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
  Trainee Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `trainees`.* FROM `trainees` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `trainees`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` = 11
  Rendering skills/filter.js.haml
  Skill Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `skills`.* FROM `skills` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `skills`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` = 5
  Skill Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `skills`.* FROM `skills` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `skills`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` = 2728
  Skill Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `skills`.* FROM `skills` INNER JOIN `mastered_skills` ON `skills`.`id` = `mastered_skills`.`skill_id` WHERE `mastered_skills`.`trainee_id` = 10
```

Comment: `@developers.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k, v| [k, v.count]}` here you are grouping by what?

Comment: @ashvin by v.count. i'm displaying im my view trainees that match most of criteria first. like... relevance

Comment: I mean group by which column from `@developers` variable?

v.count means you are couting that group by records.

Comment: ah right @ashvin so when developers are loaded. i think its taking trainee then grouping by the number of time they have occurred in the array. When i run it, it responds with `{#<Trainee id: 1>=>[#<Trainee id: 1>, #<Trainee id: 1>], #<Trainee id: 2> => [#<Trainee id: 2>, #<Trainee id: 2>, #<Trainee id: 2>]}`
yeah i think it is grouping the occurences of trainee object together to prepare for count (i didnt write that part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first `@skills` can be defined as:
`@skills = params[:ids].nil? ? Skill.all : Skills.where(id: params[:ids])`

Then you faced to `n+1` problem. To avoid it you have to use [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) (ELA) or joins.

To return **trainees** object with ELA you can use `map` and `flatten`.

Next you have a good part:

```
@developers = @developers.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k, v| [k, v.count]}
@developers.sort_by!(&:last).reverse!
```

`sort_by(&:last).reverse` works fast.

This part:

```
@developers.map! do |developer|
  developer[0]
end
```

Can be changed to:

```
@developers.map(&:first)
```

And united with previous `sort_by`:

```
@developers = @developers.sort_by(&:last).reverse.map(&:first)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for breaking it down and I understood this and pretty much made it a big part of my solution which I'm going to put here

Answer (score 1):

Optimize this part:

```
@skills = Skill.all
@developers = []
unless params[:ids].nil?
  params[:ids].each do |skill|
    skill = @skills.find(skill)
    skill.trainees.each do |developer|
      @developers << developer
    end
  end
end
```

To:

```
@developers = Skill.where(id: params[:ids]).joins(:trainees).select('trainees.*')
```

Comment: I tried this and it almost works except it brings back a Skill object. how can i make it return a trainee object. i need to be able to apply trainee methods to the result.

Comment: Don't just throw out code, explain why it is the appropriate solution. It's the difference between giving someone a fish versus teaching them to fish. See "[teach, don't merely answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291533/128421)".

Comment: @ORYON100 in above this will return trainees object, check `@developers .first.attributes`

Comment: @theTinMan You are right that we do not have to give direct answer, we should explain him to what is solution and how to go wit proper solution.

But sometime its very difficult to explain in text. we can give link for R & D.

Answer (score 0):

The issue described looks like a `N+1 problem`. Eager-loading associations might help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: yes i have read a bit on eager loading. but that is half the issue. my main issue is the method and how it can be refactored better

Answer (score 0):

If developers have many skills through trainees:

```
class Developer
  has_many :trainees
  has_many :skills, through: :trainees
end
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
@developers = Developer.where(skills: {id: params[:ids]})
```

Alternatively, you could probably get away with one less join by using:

```
@developers = Developer.where(trainees: {skill_id: params[:ids]})
```

Comment: there isnt a developer model. its trainee that can be triggered with a boolean to be a developer.
`class Trainee
  scope :developers, -> { where(finished_course: true) }
end'

Comment: So: `Trainee.where(skill_id: params[:ids], finished_course: true)`

Answer (score 0):

using most of the solution from @idej i have now gotten my code to a better state. I think it can be simplified even more but i am happy with this. and any more answers are welcome

```
  def filter
    @skills = params[:ids].nil? ? Skill.all : Skill.where(id: params[:ids])
    @developers = @skills.inject([]) do |result, skill|
      result << skill.trainees
    end
    @developers = @developers.flatten.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k, v| [k, v.count]}
    @developers.sort_by!(&:last).reverse!.map!(&:first)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```